# My url is not updating when I go to a new page on my Django site

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am building a site in django with a clickable calendrer feature. The user can click on each date and it sends them to a new page which they can book a time on that day for a session. The issue is that the URL once the user clicks on the date they want stays the same as the first page. E.g
First page
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mainsite/book_now
after clicking on a date
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mainsite/book_now
but it should be
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mainsite/time_booking
but the html of that page is loading but the view function for the page is not running

```
def book_now(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        return render(request, "client_mainsite/book_now.html")
    elif request.method == "POST":
        date = str(request.POST.get("date"))
        context = {
        }
        response = render(request, 'client_mainsite/time_booking.html', context)
        response.set_cookie('date', date)
        print(date)
        return response
    return render(request, "client_mainsite/book_now.html")
```

```
def time_booking(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        return render(request, "client_mainsite/time_booking.html")
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        context = {
            'date':request.COOKIES['date'],
        }
        time = request.POST['time']
        print("below is time")
        print(time)
        print("above is time")
        response = render(request, 'client_mainsite/time_booking.html', context)
        response.set_cookie('time', time)
        print(time + "checker")
        return response
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('book_now', views.book_now, name="bookNow"),
    path('contact_us', views.contact_us, name="contactUs"),
    path('session_history', views.session_history, name="sessionHistory"),
    path('booked', views.booked, name="booked"),
    path('detail_updater', views.detail_updater, name="detailUpdater"),
    path('session_list', views.session_list, name="sessionList"),
    path('no_go_time_day', views.no_go_time_day, name="noGoTimeDay"),
    path('time_booking', views.time_booking, name="timeBooking"),
]
```

Comment: You are returning html rendered page, not redirect to time_booking page. You should return HttpResponseRedirect

Answer (score 0):

Actually the question is not clear enough.
But if you need to return to **time_booking function** after POST request in **book_now** function,

```
def book_now(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        return render(request, "client_mainsite/book_now.html")
    elif request.method == "POST":
        date = str(request.POST.get("date"))
        context = {
        }
        response = render(request, 'client_mainsite/time_booking.html', context)
        response.set_cookie('date', date)
        print(date)
        return response
    return render(request, "client_mainsite/book_now.html")
```

In your code if this line makes problem, there is no need to write it like that:

```
 response = render(request, 'client_mainsite/time_booking.html', context)
```

Instead of the code above, you can directly return to this function like that:

```
return time_booking(request)
```